# Como añadir ceros a la izquierda a un string

Tags: c#, c

Hola me gustaria saber como puedo añadir x ceros a la izquierda segun los digitos que obtenga es decir si tengo 111 quiero tener 000111 si recibo 11 quiero tener 000011.

Esto es un string

```
linea.documento = fields[0]
```

Comment: Tienes una longitud definida para ese string?

Comment: Delimita cual  de los 2 lenguajes que pones en las etiquetas usas

Comment: Creo que con Pad puedes hacerlo.   TuCadena.PadLeft(6, '0')

Comment: Gracias Dany me sirvió

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

como comenta Dany, el modo más óptimo de hacerlo, ***en C#*** es utilizando `tuCadena.PadLeft(longitud, caracterDeRelleno)`.

Adicionalmente, modifiqué el método que hice originalmente para la pregunta, por si pudiera servir de algo:

```
public string RellenarCadena(string cadenaARellenar, char caracterDeRelleno, int longitud, bool izquierda){
     //dependiendo hacia donde queramos rellenar, es lo que devolvemos
     if(izquierda){
         return cadenaARellenar.PadLeft(longitud,caracterDeRelleno);
     }else{
        return cadenaARellenar.PadRight(longitud,caracterDeRelleno);
     }
}
```

Este método, lo que hace, es recibir una cadena que es la que queremos rellenar, con qué carácter debe rellenarse, y la longitud que debe tener la cadena a rellenar. para utilizarlo, puedes llamarlo así:

```
//deseamos que este string termine siendo "00010"
string numero="10";
numero=RellenarCadena(numero,'0',5,true);
Console.WriteLine(numero); //esto devuelve "00010"!
```

Comment: Ya que los `strings` en C# son **inmutables**, estás creando un objeto nuevo por cada iteración dentro del while. Si fuesen 200 dígitos de relleno, y nos pasan una cadena de length 1, `cadenaARellenar` sería creada 199 veces. Yo recomendaría la respuesta de Dany, que utiliza `public String PadLeft(int totalWidth, char paddingChar);`

Comment: desonocía de la existencia de ese método, pero sí, es mejor lo que comenta Dany.

Comment: Y esta respuesta es en c# o en c??? :p.. no habria que editar la pregunta para que refleje eso?

Comment: c#, re corrigiendo :P

Answer (score 0):

Si bien tenemos como te comentan ["PadLeft/PadRight" para el relleno/padding de cadenas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding) y es lo mas óptimo la mayoria de las veces, ... arme un proyecto [padding-strings-dotnet-benchmark](https://github.com/fernandezja/padding-strings-dotnet-benchmark) con otras opciones por ejemplo para probar un padding de 10000 (diez mil) con este ejemplo:
Data Test:

- inputText: "The Force will be with you always"
- totalWidth: 10000
- paddingChar: !

Y allí el mas rápido no fue PadRight por ejemplo, pero si le que menos Allocated memory tiene. Así que dejo por aquí los benchmark y el [código en en repositorio](https://github.com/fernandezja/padding-strings-dotnet-benchmark)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El codigo de test [StringPadding.cs](https://github.com/fernandezja/padding-strings-dotnet-benchmark/blob/main/src/StringPadding.Core/StringPadding.cs)

```
 public class StringPadding
{
    public string PadRight(string inputText, int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
    {
        return inputText.PadRight(totalWidth: totalWidth, paddingChar: paddingChar);
    }

    public string PadRightWithConcat(string inputText, int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
    {
        return string.Concat(inputText, new string(paddingChar, totalWidth - inputText.Length));
    }

    public string PadRightWithInterpolation(string inputText, int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
    {
        return $"{inputText}{new string(paddingChar, totalWidth - inputText.Length)}";
    }

    public string PadRightWithConcatEnumerableRepeat(string inputText, int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
    {
        return string.Concat(inputText, string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(paddingChar, totalWidth - inputText.Length)));
    }

    public string PadRightWithInterpolationEnumerableRepeat(string inputText, int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
    {
        return $"{inputText}{string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(paddingChar, totalWidth - inputText.Length))}";
    }

    public string PadRightWithCharArray(string inputText, int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
    {
        var times = totalWidth - inputText.Length;

        int limit = (int)Math.Log(times, 2);
        char[] buffer = new char[times];
        int width = 1;
        Array.Copy(new char[1] { paddingChar }, buffer, 1);

        for (int index = 0; index < limit; index++)
        {
            Array.Copy(buffer, 0, buffer, width, width);
            width *= 2;
        }

        char[] inputBuffer = new char[totalWidth];

        Array.Copy(inputText.ToCharArray(), inputBuffer, inputText.Length);
        Array.Copy(buffer, 0, inputBuffer, inputText.Length, times);

        return new string(inputBuffer);
    }

    public string PadRightWithStringBuilder(string inputText, int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(inputText);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < (totalWidth - inputText.Length); i++)
        {
            sb.Append(paddingChar);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public string PadRightWithStringBuilderInsert(string inputText, int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(inputText);

        sb.Insert(inputText.Length, paddingChar.ToString(), totalWidth - inputText.Length);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public string PadRightWithReadOnlySpan(string inputText, int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
    {
        var inputTextSpan = inputText.AsSpan();
        var paddingCharSpan = (new string(paddingChar, totalWidth - inputText.Length)).AsSpan();


        return string.Concat(inputText, paddingCharSpan);
    }


    public string PadRightWithZStringConcat(string inputText, int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
    {

        return ZString.Concat(inputText, new string(paddingChar, totalWidth - inputText.Length));
    }

    public string PadRightWithZStringStringBuilderForAppend(string inputText, int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
    {
        var zsb = ZString.CreateStringBuilder();
        zsb.Append(inputText);

        for (int i = 0; i < (totalWidth - inputText.Length); i++)
        {
            zsb.Append(paddingChar);
        }

        return zsb.ToString();
    }

    public string PadRightWithZStringStringBuilderNewString(string inputText, int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
    {
        var zsb = ZString.CreateStringBuilder();
        zsb.Append(inputText);
        zsb.Append(new string(paddingChar, totalWidth - inputText.Length));
        return zsb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Dejo un repo si puede servir de ayuda o guia

- [padding-strings-dotnet-benchmark](https://github.com/fernandezja/padding-strings-dotnet-benchmark)